# Creating new and empty string array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to split input from the command line by spaces.

```
for (int len = 4; len > 0; len--) {
   int command = System.in.read(cmdString);
   String commandWhole = new String(cmdString); //Gives us a string that we can parse
   String[] commandPieces = commandWhole.split("\\s*+");
}
```

If I input "hello world" I will have commandPieces[0] = "hello" and commandPieces[1] = "world". That's perfect. However, if I then input "test" I will have commandPieces[0] = "test" and commandPieces[1] = "world" but I don't want there to be a commandPieces[1].

How can I make a new String array for each iteration of the for loop. 
Something like:

```
String[] commandPieces = new String[]{commandWhole.split("\\s*+")};
```

which obviously won't work since split returns a string array.

Thanks

Comment: *if I then input "test" I will have commandPieces[0] = "test" and commandPieces[1] = "world"* => are you sure?

Comment: This should never have to be done since world should never be in command line arguments if only test is input

Comment: OP would be using the same variable again ...

Comment: Oh I get it, just reset your string each time that is why world is still there

Comment: how is `cmdString` declared? move this declaration inside loop

Comment: I declared cmdString as "byte cmdString[] = new byte[MAX_LEN];" So I should be resetting this "cmdString" array each time as opposed to the commandPieces array. It works now thanks! @Lashane

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler Way

```
  String[] commPice = wholeCommand.split(what ever);
```

The Array will by created automaticly

Comment: isn' this what he's doing?

Comment: Yes, he is never resetting the variable, thus why world is still in the array

Answer (score 0):

you can use this type of code

```
public class TestSplitScanner {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int noOfTimestoReadFrom = 4;

      for (int i = 0; i < noOfTimestoReadFrom; i++) {
        String next = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] split = next.split("\\s+");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));

       }

     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll just summarize what I learned from the comments in my question. 
Instead of creating a new commandPieces array with each iteration, I changed it so that the cmdString array was reset with each iteration. The code now looks like:

```
for (int len = 4; len > 0; len--) {
   byte cmdString[] = new byte[MAX_LEN];
   int command = System.in.read(cmdString);
   String commandWhole = new String(cmdString); //Gives us a string that we can parse
   String[] commandPieces = commandWhole.split("\\s*+");
}
```

Reading the documentation for read, each line of input was stored in cmdString as bytes. So inputting "hello world" stored "hello world" in the cmdString array. Then inputting "test" would change the first few bytes of cmdString but wasn't long enough to write over "world".

With each iteration, commandPieces was splitting the string value of the cmdString array. By redeclaring this array each time, it removes previous inputs.